# CakePHP: Strip HTML using Text helper?

Tags: php, cakephp, helper

I'm using the truncate method of the text helper and in doing so means any html included in the text is being rendered. Is there anyway to set the text helper to strip out html tags?

```
           echo $text->truncate(    
                $project['Project']['description'], 
                250,   
                array(
                    'ending' => '...', 
                    'exact' => false
                )
            );
```

Is there a modification to this similar to the **stripLinks** method?

thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo $text->truncate(    
            $project['Project']['description'], 
            250,   
            array(
                'ending' => '...', 
                'exact' => false,
                'html' => true
            )
        );
```

that will make it respect the html structure. you can always use strip_tags(), there is nothing wrong with using php functions in cake :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use `Sanitize::html($badString)`
See [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1185/html).

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong but won't this just change html tags into text. so it will display the html tags but just not as html

Comment: Using `'remove' => true` in the `$options` array removes the HTML tags.